# Log Out of Google Sign In and return user to Login page: Swift/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, google-signin

I have successfully created a Google Sign In for my app, which works fine, so that if the user is logged in, the user will be taken to a tab controller.

Now, I have sign out buttons on both of the items in the tab controller, so that the user is able to sign out. I want to know how to make it so that the user can click the sign out button, which will successfully sign them out of Google in the app, and then return the user to the Login page.

**Here is a screenshot of my Main.storyboard:**

[MainStoryboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hNnf.png)

**Here is the code for my AppDelegate File:**

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FIRApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().hasAuthInKeychain() {
            print("User has been successfully signed in with Google")
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabController") as? UITabBarController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        } else {
            print("User has failed in signing in with Google")
            let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            if let tabBarVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogInViewController") as? ViewController {
                window!.rootViewController = tabBarVC
            }
        }

        return true
    }



    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
        let credentials = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
        })
    }


    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {



        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                          sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!,
                                          annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

**And if needed, ViewController.swift file:**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        setupGoogleButtons()
    }

    fileprivate func setupGoogleButtons() {
        //add google sign in button
        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)
        //custom google button
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 66 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        customButton.backgroundColor = .orange
        customButton.setTitle("Custom Google Sign In", for: .normal)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomGoogleSign), for: .touchUpInside)
        customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        view.addSubview(customButton)

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    }

    func handleCustomGoogleSign() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is easy to do:

When you logout in the `action`, you just set the `window`'s rootvc to `logint vc`

```
window!.rootViewController = login vc
```

Comment: Hi, do you put this function in the IBAction function before the viewdidload or inside?

Comment: Also, do I put this in a file that is just for that tab controller item, because when I put in window!.rootViewController, window! is unresolved.

Comment: @RakeshKumar  logout action.